# when to use 講座/ チュートリアル / 学習用

Tags: word-choice

I have seen many websites use 講座 (to teach something) but generally aren't all 3 terms the same?

Can someone give example of each usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each has very different original meaning, but in a specific context they can be used to describe the same thing

- 講座｛こうざ｝ a lecture, a course

  originally a lecture / course you attend at school/seminar (with lecturer), however also referring to the contents (curriculum) when used for a book / study materials
- チュートリアル a tutorial

  straight from English "tutorial" with the same meaningーmaterial for self-study
- 学習用 for study (like in "material for studying")

  a noun 学習｛がくしゅう｝ meaning "study, learning" combined with 用｛よう｝ the purpose / use of the preceding noun

In case of learning materials for self-study indeed you could use the above terms interchangeably, like "A course in Java", "A Java tutorial", "Java for self-learners", but you would never call a lecture at the university "a tutorial".